# Manifolds, where its enough to have one chart for integration

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, volume

Assume a compact connected manifold $M$ is given as a subset of some $\mathbb{R}^m$. Assume we have a chart $\gamma:U \rightarrow M$ such that $M-f(U)$ (the set $M$ without $f(U)$) has zero measure in $M$ and call this property **. Then its enough to have this one chart to calculate the volume of $M$ (example: remove a point from a sphere). While there is the construction of a partition of one to calculate the volume in case one needs more charts, I think I never saw an example of a calculation where $M$ did not have the property ** and one really had to construct a partition of unity.(Simple textbook examples like, spheres, torus etc all seem to have property **)
So can one classify all such manifolds having property **?

Comment: maybe i am wrong but wouldn't the torus be an example?

Comment: no if you cut out two circles, you can get his volume with one chart. choose $U=(0,2 \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi)$.

Comment: u are right ,sorry :)

Comment: Every compact manifold has a chart whose complement is measure zero. I do not know an easy proof of this.

Comment: do you know a reference?

Comment: @Mare: On a Riemannian manifold the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Riemannian_geometry%29) from an arbitrary point $p$ is surjective. Fix $p$, and let $U$ be the largest open set in $T_{p}M$ that contains $p$ and whose image does not hit the [cut locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_%28Riemannian_manifold%29). The exponential map furnishes a parametrization $\exp:U \to M$ whose image is dense and has full measure. (There are details to check, but that's one sketch.)

Comment: sounds interesting, hope you could make an answer out of it filling some details ;)